# How can I use "do you be"?

Tags: aspect, linking-verbs, progressive-aspect

Example with [a context](http://vocaroo.com/i/s0tpGxs77W4b) (audio):

> Yeah, when you don't know somebody very well and they just unload all this information on you, you don't really know how to deal with that situation. **Do you be** supportive, do you back away? It's awkward for everybody.

Do you think it is grammatically alright to say *do you be*? Doesn't that sound kind of wrong to you? Or, maybe, this is some sort of colloquialism that's ungrammatical, but people still use it in an informal setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually *be* is just a copula ('linking') verb; but when it is cast in imperative or progressive constructions, or employed with *do* support, it is a dynamic verb with the approximate sense "behave".

- John is a jerk *means John is always a jerk: jerkness is his defining characteristic.*
- John is being a jerk *means John is, for the moment, behaving like a jerk: at other times he behaves differently.*
- Don't be such a jerk, John *enjoins John to cease behaving like a jerk.*

The colloquial use here, with *do* support, similarly distinguishes this *be* as dynamic rather than copular. It's sort of awkward, but convenient.

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatical but you've transcribed it slightly wrong, he says "do you be supportive" (there's no **of**).

He's [making a list](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/colons.asp):

> Yeah, when you don't know somebody very well and they just unload all this information on you, you don't really know how to deal with that situation: do you be supportive, do you back away? It's awkward for everybody.